# JPA persistence CrudRepository.save() syntax error

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, persistence, spring-data-jpa

I'm working on an Airline Management system where I'm accessing a mysql database via JPA CrudRepository methods.
Whenever I try to save a flight object into the database using repository.save(flightObject), it throws following error -

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from, capacity, manufacturer, model, plane, yearofmanufacture, price, seatsleft,' at line 1
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:943)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3970)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3906)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2524)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2677)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2549)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1861)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2073)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2009)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:5098)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1994)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:204)
```

My flight creation function is as follows -

```
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/flight/{flight_number}")
        public Flight createUpdateFlight(@PathVariable(value = "flight_number") String flightNumber, @RequestParam(value="price") int price, @RequestParam(value="from") String from, @RequestParam(value="to") String to, @RequestParam(value="departuretime") String departuretime, @RequestParam(value="arrivaltime") String arrivaltime,@RequestParam(value="seatsleft") int seatsleft, @RequestParam("description") String description, @RequestParam(value="capacity") int capacity, @RequestParam(value="manufacturer") String manufacturer,@RequestParam(value="model") String model,@RequestParam(value="yearofmanufacture") String yearofmanufacture) throws ParseException {

            DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM d, yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
            Date arrivaldate = format.parse(arrivaltime);
            Date departuredate = format.parse(departuretime);

            Plane plane = new Plane(capacity,model,manufacturer,yearofmanufacture);

            Flight flight = new Flight(flightNumber, price, from, to, departuredate, arrivaldate, seatsleft, description, plane, null);

            try{
                flightRepository.save(flight);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return flightRepository.findBynumber(flight.getNumber());
        }
```

My flight repository class -

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public interface FlightRepository extends CrudRepository<Flight, String> {
    Flight findBynumber(String number);
}
```

My flight entity class is as follows -

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "flight")
@XmlRootElement
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class, property="@id")
public class Flight {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "number")
    private String number; // Each flight has a unique flight number.

    @Column(name = "price")
    private int price;

    @Column(name = "from")
    private String from;

    @Column(name = "to")
    private String to;

    @Column(name = "departuretime")
    private Date departureTime;

    @Column(name = "arrivaltime")
    private Date arrivalTime;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "seatsleft")
    private int seatsLeft;


    //@OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    //@JoinColumn(name="plane")
    @Embedded
    private Plane plane; // Embedded


    @OneToMany()
    @JoinTable(
              name="passenger_list",
              joinColumns=
                { @JoinColumn(name="number") },//, referencedColumnName="number"),
              inverseJoinColumns=
                 @JoinColumn(name="passenger" , referencedColumnName="id" ))
    private List<Passenger> passengers;


    public Flight(String number, int price, String from, String to, Date departureTime, Date arrivalTime,
            int seatsLeft, String description, Plane plane, List<Passenger> passengers) {
        super();
        System.out.println("Inside Flight constr");
        this.number = number;
        this.price = price;
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
        this.departureTime = departureTime;
        this.arrivalTime = arrivalTime;
        this.description = description;
        this.seatsLeft = seatsLeft;
        this.plane = plane;
        this.passengers = passengers;
    }


    public Flight()
    {
        super();
    }

    public String getNumber() {
        return number;
    }
    public void setNumber(String number) {
        this.number = number;
    }
    public int getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
    public void setPrice(int price) {
        this.price = price;
    }
    public String getFrom() {
        return from;
    }
    public void setFrom(String from) {
        this.from = from;
    }
    public String getTo() {
        return to;
    }
    public void setTo(String to) {
        this.to = to;
    }
    public Date getDepartureTime() {
        return departureTime;
    }
    public void setDepartureTime(Date departureTime) {
        this.departureTime = departureTime;
    }
    public Date getArrivalTime() {
        return arrivalTime;
    }
    public void setArrivalTime(Date arrivalTime) {
        this.arrivalTime = arrivalTime;
    }
    public int getSeatsLeft() {
        return seatsLeft;
    }
    public void setSeatsLeft(int seatsLeft) {
        this.seatsLeft = seatsLeft;
    }
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
    public Plane getPlane() {
        return plane;
    }
    public void setPlane(Plane plane) {
        this.plane = plane;
    }

    public List<Passenger> getPassengers() {
        return passengers;
    }
    public void setPassengers(List<Passenger> passengers) {
        this.passengers = passengers;
    }
}
```

My embeddable plane class is as follows -

```
@Embeddable
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
public class Plane implements Serializable{

    //@Id
    @Column(name = "plane")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int plane;

    @Column(name = "capacity")
    private int capacity;

    @Column(name = "model")
    private String model;

    @Column(name = "manufacturer")
    private String manufacturer;

    @Column(name = "yearofmanufacture")
    private String yearofmanufacture;


    public Plane(int capacity, String model, String manufacturer, String yearofmanufacture) {
        super();
        System.out.println("Inside Plane constr");
        this.capacity = capacity;
        this.model = model;
        this.manufacturer = manufacturer;
        this.yearofmanufacture = yearofmanufacture;
    }

    public Plane() {
        super();
    }

    public int getId() {
        return plane;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.plane = id;
    }

    public int getCapacity() {
        return capacity;
    }

    public void setCapacity(int capacity) {
        this.capacity = capacity;
    }

    public String getModel() {
        return model;
    }

    public void setModel(String model) {
        this.model = model;
    }

    public String getManufacturer() {
        return manufacturer;
    }

    public void setManufacturer(String manufacturer) {
        this.manufacturer = manufacturer;
    }

    public String getYearofmanufacture() {
        return yearofmanufacture;
    }

    public void setYearofmanufacture(String yearofmanufacture) {
        this.yearofmanufacture = yearofmanufacture;
    }

}
```

This is my database schema image -

[image]

Please let me know if you are able to spot any mistake.
I have been trying it for quiet a while now without any success.
Can we print the JPA query to check syntax before execution?

Comment: @NeilStockton - Can you please elaborate your comment? Any ideas on how I can resolve this issue?

Comment: The `Flight` entity has `from` and `to` attributes, for which the database column names have been specified the same as well. These are keywords in databases and therefore render queries invalid. You need to wrap the column names in the query with quotes to allow the RDBMS to treat them as regular strings. See the Hibernate documentation for generating SQL queries with quoted identifiers.

Comment: Add this in your property file to print the query to the console `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=true`

Comment: @manish - The issue is resolved. Thanks a lot for pointing out the issue with from and to attributes. I would have never thought of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue has been resolved. The problem was with 'from' and 'to' attributes. 
'from' and 'to' are database keywords and therefore can't be used directly as column names in JPA entities.
Using them directly in a query makes it invalid.
Changing the column names did the trick.
Another option is to wrap the column names in quotes while writing queries so that they are not treated as keywords.

Answer (score 0):

Would be nice to see your FlightRepository structure.
I think there is a mistake in 'findBynumber' method, which syntactically can't be transformed into write query.
It should looks like 'findByNumber'.

Comment: I have added FlightRepository class in the post. I don't think there is an issue with findBynumber method. It's working fine for other requests. Please check.

Comment: What do you mean "It's working fine for other requests"? I see only one request. Or you mean 'save' method?  You have a problem with SQL query syntax. There is only one place for SQL query. Please, check how to generate Repository methods name for queries. It should be a camelCase format

Comment: I checked it. findByNumber is giving same error as findBynumber. I don't think the issue is with camel case. Other methods are able to fetch flight data correctly using findByNumber method. Issue is with this particular request.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/flight/{flight_number}")
public Flight createUpdateFlight(@PathVariable(value = "flight_number") String flightNumber, @RequestParam(value="price") int price, @RequestParam(value="from") String from, @RequestParam(value="to") String to, @RequestParam(value="departuretime") String departuretime, @RequestParam(value="arrivaltime") String arrivaltime,@RequestParam(value="seatsleft") int seatsleft, @RequestParam("description") String description, @RequestParam(value="capacity") int capacity, @RequestParam(value="manufacturer") String manufacturer,@RequestParam(value="model") String model,@RequestParam(value="yearofmanufacture") String yearofmanufacture) throws ParseException {

    DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM d, yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
    Date arrivaldate = format.parse(arrivaltime);
    Date departuredate = format.parse(departuretime);

    Plane plane = new Plane(capacity,model,manufacturer,yearofmanufacture);

    Flight flight = new Flight(flightNumber, price, from, to, departuredate, arrivaldate, seatsleft, description, plane, null);

    try{
        flight = flightRepository.save(flight); //save() method returns a Flight entity after saving it.
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return flight;
}
```

PS: I have not tested this.